# удаление через remove

Tags: javascript

Deleteblock.remove() is not function может мне кто объяснить
почему он считает его не функцией ???
как это исправить?
просто не понятно , что для него функция , а что нет?

```js
const deletePlace = document.querySelectorAll('.element__heart');
const Deleteblock = document.querySelectorAll('.block')

function del() {
  Deleteblock.remove();
}

deletePlace.forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.addEventListener('click', del)
})
```

```css
.element__heart {
  margin: 31px 22px 30px 0;
  background-color: red;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 0;
  width: 21px;
  height: 18px;
}

.block {
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.box {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='block'>
    <button class="element__heart" type="button">1</button>
  </div>
  <div class='block'>
    <button class="element__heart" type="button">2</button>
  </div>
  <div class='block'>
    <button class="element__heart" type="button">3</button>
  </div>
  <div class='block'>
    <button class="element__heart" type="button">4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: потому что селектор возвращает коллекцию.

Comment: Коллекцию? это как?

Comment: Коллекцию марок или значков. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1):

```js
const deletePlace = document.querySelectorAll('.element__heart');

function del() {
  this.closest('.block').remove();
}

deletePlace.forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.addEventListener('click', del)
})
```

```css
.element__heart {
  margin: 31px 22px 30px 0;
  background-color: red;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 0;
  width: 21px;
  height: 18px;
}

.block {
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.box {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='block'>
    <button class="element__heart" type="button">1</button>
  </div>
  <div class='block'>
    <button class="element__heart" type="button">2</button>
  </div>
  <div class='block'>
    <button class="element__heart" type="button">3</button>
  </div>
  <div class='block'>
    <button class="element__heart" type="button">4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошо, допустим, а почему твое this.closest('.block').remove(); он считает функцией?

Comment: @СашаПупкин Я не понимаю что Вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @СашаПупкин, очевидно потому, что closest возвращает один элемент, а querySelectorAll - список элементов

Comment: @lgor Deleteblock.remove() is not function----
this.closest('.block').remove(); - твое срабатывает почему? да кстати еще вопрос может я где то забыл (this) это что?

Comment: @СашаПупкин Вы уже искали это в интернете?

Comment: @Igor да искал, но толку 0
я не понимаю почему у вас каждый блок удаляется 
когда я убираю Selector(All) у меня удаляется первый блок и все

Comment: @СашаПупкин Вы уже прочитали объяснения про `querySelector` и про `querySelectorAll` на MDN?

Comment: @Igor честно Англ слабоват , так что для меня это тяжело